# YouTube iframe player - trigger fullscreen on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Using the YouTube iframe embed player, is there a way to trigger fullscreen programatically? I want to remove the default controls (using controls=0) but then have the ability to create  custom fullscreen button by itself.

Comment: You may try and look into UIWebView child views for a AVPlayer class , and put its layer to full screen

Answer (score 4):

Make the iframe not fullscreen but fullpage:

```js
    function fullscreen() {
        var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
        vid.style.position = "absolute";
        vid.style.width = "100vw";
        vid.style.height = "100vh";
        vid.style.top = "0px";
        vid.style.left = "0px";
        document.getElementById("exit").style.display = "inline";
    }
    function exitfullscreen() {
      var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
      vid.style.position = "";
      vid.style.width = "";
      vid.style.height = "";
      vid.style.top = "";
      vid.style.left = "";
      document.getElementById("exit").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fq6qcvfZldE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" id="vid" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <button onClick="fullscreen()">Fullscreen</button>
    <button style="position: fixed; 
                   bottom: 5px; 
                   right: 5px; 
                   display: none;
                   z-index: 2000;" id="exit" onClick="exitfullscreen()">Exit Fullscreen</button>
```

The <kbd>full page</kbd> button in the right upper corner of the code snippet also works this way. If you want to make the browser full screen you could try `document.requestFullscreen();`, but this is still experimental and works on very few browsers. Take a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) topic of this function.

EDIT: Just found this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/?csw=1#player_apis, the official youtube player API.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in Webkit browsers:

```
if (typeof iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen === 'function') {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }, false);
}
```

Note that this won't work without a user gesture (in this case, 'click').

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) instead of iframe player.
Its very simple and powerful. Supports full-screen as well as non  full-screen.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: Its dont :) its just an alternative solution of what he want to achieve (and probably is the fastest and easies way)