# YTPlayerView controls settings don't affect fullscreen mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I'm trying to play a youtube video in my iOS app using "YTPlayerView".
My aim is to play video in fullscreen, don't show any controls, and close it on the first tap to the screen.
If I play video inline, everything works properly, but in fullscreen control-bars appear. However, if I close fullscreen with its button (on the bottom right), controls disappear.

```
var playerVars = [AnyHashable : Any]()
playerVars["enablejsapi"] = 1
playerVars["rel"] = 0
playerVars["fs"] = 0
playerVars["controls"] = 0
playerVars["iv_load_policy"] = 3
playerVars["modestbranding"] = 1
playerVars["playsinline"] = 0
playerVars["showinfo"] = 0
self.playerView.load(withVideoId: videoId, playerVars: playerVars)
```

Any help will be very appreciated to solve this issue.

**Image about full screen with control-bars**

[image]

Comment: Im using this [pod 'YouTubePlayer'](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) & it is working fine. you can try this library.

Comment: Thank you @dahiya_boy, I've just tried it, but it is still the same. I added an image about my fullscreen video.

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361825/youtube-iframe-player-trigger-fullscreen-on-ios)?

Comment: Thank you @jess, it was a good idea!

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Comment: take a look at this API example: https://github.com/malkouz/youtube-ios-player-helper-swift

Answer (score 0):

"rel" and "info" depricated. Try this - 
"playsinline"
This parameter controls whether videos play inline or fullscreen in an HTML5 player on iOS. Valid values are:
0: This value causes fullscreen playback. This is currently the default value, though the default is subject to change.
1: This value causes inline playback for UIWebViews created with the allowsInlineMediaPlayback property set to TRUE.